# Как добавить js скрипты и свои css стили(расширение) в exe файл?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, exe

1. Я добавила расширение для определенного сайта(не мой сайт), там куча моих скриптов и стилей.(просто добавляются автоматически js и css, как tempermonkey)
2. В голову появилась задача! создать exe файл сайта, типо нажимая на exe у нас открывает окно и сайт.// ненужен браузер,будет как НЕДОПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (С этой задачей я справилась)
3. вот тут мне уже нужна ваша помощь,(ваши идеи),  как совместить exe  и файлы js и css в одну кучу.

Comment: А поделитесь используемой технологией, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

[Electron](https://electronjs.org/) от GitHub (Microsoft), [Carlo](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/carlo) от Google, [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) от Intel или [QWebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webengine-minimal-example.html) (требует написание C++ кода на готовых примерах, но обеспечивает относительную защиту кода нетиповым решением)